# Continuity of an intergral

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a simplified version of a problem that I encountered. I have to show continuity wrt $x$ of a function $g$ which maps $x$ to an integral

$$ g(x) = \int_{\Omega} f(x) dx .$$

We can assume $f$ to be smooth, $\Omega$ is a bounded.  I looked at it and without thinking too much wrote

$$ |g(x_n) - g(x)| = | \int_{\Omega} f(x_n) - f(x) dx| \leq \int_{\Omega} |f(x_n) - f(x)| dx \rightarrow 0 $$

for a convergent sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$. But is this question well posed? I'm having doubts because the variable $x$ is the same variable with respect to which it's being integrated. My question is how to show continuity of a function defined in this way.

Comment: Your function $g$ is constant since it doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: I find the initial formula confusing.  What is the dependence on the $x$ on the left-hand-side.  Is the continuity to be shown in a space of functions?

Comment: Oh indeed it is constant, thank you for pointing that out. I don't know why I got confused. And regarding the second comment: no, it's not an operator, the continuity I was looking for was actually wrt to variable x.